# How can I upload files only with type image in asp.net mvc2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I want to upload Images only with file upload in asp.net mvc2 and show validation for the user in client side using jquery or mvc validation and server side also.
any one can help?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. Could you describe in more detail what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload an file without posting to the server. You could also take a look at the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) which allows you to AJAXify a form and [supports file uploads](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) as well (behind the scenes it uses a hidden iframe because files cannot be uploaded using AJAX).